# Intro CS class - ifstream/ofstream struggle C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I just learned about coding with files last week and it's kind of confusing me. The objective is to have the user input 3 numbers which saves to a file, then write 3 additional numbers while the .txt file is open and save. The program runs but I encounter 4 problems. In my "if" statement, it says "outfile is undefined", "outfile is undeclared", and "left of '.fail' must have class/struct/union". Also, my last cout statement doesn't display even though Visual Studio didn't consider that an error. My code looks just like my professor's sample programs, I can't figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("data.txt", ios::app);
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;
if (outfile.fail());
{
    cout << "File did not open.\n";
        return 1;
}
cout << "Enter three integers: \n";
cin >> num1;
cin >> num2;
cin >> num3;

outFile << num1 << endl << num2 << endl << num3;
outFile.close();
cout << "The data has been written to file.";
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Typo. `outfile` -> `outFile`.

Comment: `outfile` is not the same thing as `outFile`. Also, your keyboard appears to be broken, and its `TAB` key does not appear to work all the time. Because of that, the shown code is mostly unreadable due to lack of logical indentation. Please replace your keyboard, and reindent your code, logically, so that it is readable.

Comment: wow, thank you so much. Lastly though, why is my final cout statement not displaying?

Comment: Edit: my final cout statement is displaying on the .txt file but I need it on the display screen

Comment: `if (outfile.fail());` is wrong. Remove the `;` and things will be better. Although with that said a minute or 2 spent using your debugger would have told you that..